# Adding iterations together in Java

Tags: java, iteration

I'm trying to add together the sum of the iterations of a for loop. This is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pennies
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        double amount; //To hold the amount of pennies per day
        double days; //To hold the days user saved.
        double total;

        System.out.println("I will display a table of salary if you're paid every day in pennies and it doubles every day.");

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many days do you wish to save for?");
        days = keyboard.nextDouble();

        //Display the table
        System.out.print("Day \t Salary \n");
        for (amount = 1; amount <= days; amount++)
        {
            total = amount * .01 * amount;
            System.out.println(amount + "\t \t $" + total);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: What is the desired output and what is the current output that is to be improved?

Comment: The desired output would be a table that displays the salary doubling every day and then at the bottom, there would be the total of all the iterations.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep on adding the salary for each day and keeping the track of total for each day (as I get it from your statement), you can change:-

```
total = amount * .01 * amount;
```

to

```
total += amount * .01 * amount; // total = total + (amount*0.01*amount)
```

which(when not printing each day information separately) can be simplified as:-

```
total = amount * .01 * amount * days;
```

Answer (score 0):

I compiled your code and noticed that your numbers were off. Assuming that you want the first day's pay to be one penny, and for it to double every following day, here's what I came up with. It's hard to tell if this is exactly what you want since you didn't actually ask a question, so let me know if this is what you're looking for.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out
            .println("I will display a table of salary if you're paid every day in pennies and it doubles every day.");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many days do you wish to save for?");
    double days = keyboard.nextDouble();

    // Display the table
    System.out.print("Day \t Salary \n");
    double pay = 0.01;
    double totalPay = 0.0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + "\t \t $" + pay);
        totalPay += pay;
        pay *= 2;
    }
    System.out.println("Total Pay \t $" + totalPay);
    keyboard.close();
}
```

You're originally doing `total = amount*0.1*amount`, which won't give you what you want. You're confusing squaring `amount` with simply doubling it.

Edit: Also consider changing `days` to an `int`. I don't see any reason why it should be a `double`

Comment: I'm trying to add together the iterations of the loop. .4+.6+.8+ etc and come up with the total of the iterations at the end.